# Disable Overclocking on Asus motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, freeze, uefi, overclocking

I have bought an ASUS ROG STRIX Z590-F which has overclocking capabilities. However, I noticed that by default my PC has random freezes. The image stays on the monitors but the computer is not responding, I have to force restart.

I am not exactly sure, but I think it is due to the default overclocking Load-Line and Current Capability. If I move the cursors to Level 1 and 100%, I don't get any freezes.

[image]

How can I disable this feature by default? I've looked on the UEFI menu but didn't find a "Disable overclocking" option.

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Are there mechanical switches on the board designed to control the overclock capability? Once set it should not be overclocking. Yes; Your issue is likely an unstable overclock situation

Comment: I don't see any mechanical switches on the motherboard

Comment: So I don't understand the problem.  Are these options being changed, once you set them, from outside of the firmware? Do you have third-party software that perhaps might be controlling your overclock.  ASUS does have software that allows you to perform an overclock.  While your problem set is clear (your system is in an unstable overclock), what isn't clear, is what exactly your question is.

Comment: Each time I change them they are reset when I reboot

Comment: Your question does not make that fact clear.  However, I asked several other questions, I have my theories on what is happening.